# Unable to install Extensions after changing hosts

Tags: extensions, migration, configuration

Since I've switch web hosts, every time I try to install an extension this error comes up.

```
Error
Archive does not exist

Warning
JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: C:/xampp/htdocs/Joomla/Folix-1/tmp/install_549300109e8e0
JFolder: :folder: Path is not a folder. Path: C:/xampp/htdocs/Joomla/Folix-1/tmp/install_549300109e8e0
JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: C:/xampp/htdocs/Joomla/Folix-1/tmp/install_549300109e8e0
JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file\
```

Should I change the `public $tmp_path = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Joomla\\Folix-1/tmp';` in configuration.php ?

If yes, which path should I insert? 
I'm not using cPanel. I'm using Parallels Panel, so I'm not sure about the path. 
Here's how my folders look like: `Root directory > httpdocs > tmp`

Comment: have a look at https://docs.joomla.org/Why_can't_you_install_any_extensions%3F

Comment: I'm not familiar with Parallels, but you can try setting `public $tmp_path` to `/vhosts/domainname.tld/httpdocs/tmp` or `/httpdocs/logs` (depends on your host)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, it's the tmp path that needs to be correctly defined for your new server. I would also suggest you change the log path at the same time.

From this:

```
public $log_path = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Joomla\\Folix-1/logs';
public $tmp_path = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Joomla\\Folix-1/tmp';
```

to this:

```
public $log_path = '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/logs';
public $tmp_path = '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/tmp';
```

It should say somewhere in your Host control panel file manager what the USER is.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! I don't have a public_html folder. Is it ok, if I use httpdocs? `public $tmp_path = 'home/domain.com/httpdocs/tmp';` (It seems my user has the same name as my domain.)

Comment: Oh and I don't have a "home". It doesn't appear on files paths.

Comment: Sorry, i missed the part where you said you weren't using cPanel. Try adding `<?php echo basepath(__FILE__); ?>` to something like your template index.php file and see what the value is. This should give you your absolute path which you can add to your `$tmp_path`. When you add it, don't include the `templates/my_template/` part of the path

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function basepath() in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/templates/protostar/index.php on line 1`

so is it `public $tmp_path = 'var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/temp';` or `public $tmp_path = '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/temp';` ?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. Use basename instead

Comment: basename only gave the name of the file: `index.php`. I tried `<?php echo dirname(__FILE__); ?>` and as result: `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/templates/protostar`

Comment: @JoanaRijo - Ah ok. I've updated my answer based on your results. Try changing your configuration.php file with what I have in my answer, then try installing an extension again